# Android: Unfortunately _____ Has stopped

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am trying to run one of the example programs that goes over menus and how they work.  But whenever I try to compile and run the example I get the error in the title and am unable to see if any of the menu options are working.

Probably something so simple, but I am tired and frustrated at this point :(

```
package com.example.context_menu_demo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button m_button;
 RelativeLayout ourlayout;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ourlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
  m_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_but);
  registerForContextMenu(m_button);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
   ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.red:
   ourlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
   break;

  case R.id.green:
   ourlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
   break;
  case R.id.blue:
   ourlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

   break;
  case R.id.gray:
   ourlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
   break;
  case R.id.cyan:
   ourlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
   break;
  case R.id.yellow:
   ourlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
   break;

  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

xmls

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_id">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu_but"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:text="Menu" />


    <item android:id="@+id/red" android:title="RED"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/green" android:title="GREEN"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/blue" android:title="BLUE"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/gray" android:title="GRAY"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/cyan" android:title="CYAN"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/yellow" android:title="YELLOW"></item>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xmls

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/red" android:title="RED"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/green" android:title="GREEN"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/blue" android:title="BLUE"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/gray" android:title="GRAY"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/cyan" android:title="CYAN"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/yellow" android:title="YELLOW"></item>
</menu>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.context_menu_demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.context_menu_demo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you show us your logcat error

Comment: remove the menu items in layout xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of these lines inside your RelativeLayout you are getting exception..Remove this lines...

```
 <item android:id="@+id/red" android:title="RED"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/green" android:title="GREEN"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/blue" android:title="BLUE"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/gray" android:title="GRAY"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/cyan" android:title="CYAN"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/yellow" android:title="YELLOW"></item>
```

bacause of these lines i think you will get `InflaterException`..

Answer (score 1):

You can't have Item tag in your activity layout  `<item    ... ></item>`